# Using a checkbox to hide a row

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I'm trying to code a macro that uses a checkbox click to hide the row the checkbox is in.  I've a task list of about 100 tasks and want to assign each row its own checkbox, so when the user clicks the box the row gets hidden from the remaining tasks.

Comment: Do you have anything to show for what you are asking? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

The following video is a tutorial on how to accomplish hiding a row using a checkbox (you'll see your specific functionality at 4:10 in the tutorial video):

[Creating a Checkbox to Hide and Unhide Rows in Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4dcIYwnvpc)

Rather than creating only one checkbox, you'll want to create one per row. So if you have 100 rows, you'll be creating 100 checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks...I tried that method earlier and was running into problems when trying to create checkboxes for the other rows.  So in this case, would there be over 100 macros, one for each checkbox, or would one macro suffice and be applied to all rows without having to edit the macro?